# how to display only 4 items per rows using struts2 ognl tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

i am trying to display 4 values in a single tr and next four values in next tr. But with my below code all the values are showing in a single tr with long horizontal scroll.

I want to show my list values : 4 values in each row and next 4 values in next tr

Please check my code  and tell me the logic to solve my problem..

```
<s:if test="themes.size() > 0">  
   <table> 
      <s:iterator value="themes" status="userStatus"> 
               <tr> 
                        <td height="90%"> 
                 <s:property value="themeName" />                     
                        </td> 
               </tr>     

     </s:iterator>  
</table>
```

**What i tried is the below code:**

```
 `<s:if test="themes.size() > 0">  
      <table>  
         <s:set var="index" value="%{0}" />
               <tr> 
                   <s:iterator value="themes" status="userStatus"> 
                        <td height="90%">
                                 <s:property value="themeName" /> 
                        </td>  
                         <s:set var="newindex" value="%{1 + #attr.index}" />   
                            <s:if test="#attr.newindex %4==0">
                                </tr><tr>
                             </s:if> 
                  </s:iterator>  
               </tr>      
          </table>   
      </s:if>
```

Comment: You are not even trying to do what you want.

Comment: @AleksandrM i am trying. At last correct output did not came so i thought to ask here

Comment: Your code shows no sign of it.

Comment: @AleksandrM I posted my code above which i tried.  Please check it above. And give me hint from it.     `Error: There is some mismatch of tags and i am not so much familiar with the the ognl tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use module:

```
<s:if test="themes.size() > 0">
    <table>         
        <s:iterator value="themes" status="currentRecord">
            <s:if test="(#currentRecord.index % 4) == 0">
            <!-- Record is First of row: 1st, 5th, 9th etc -->
                <s:if test="#currentRecord.index > 0">                  
                    </tr><!-- It's not the first, close previous row -->
                </s:if>                 
                    <tr><!-- Open row -->
            </s:if>
                        <td>
                            <s:property value="themeName" />
                        </td>                      
        </s:iterator>                       
                    </tr><!-- close last open row -->
    </table>
</s:if>
```

Comment: Do not forget about octothorpe! :)

Comment: @AleksandrM I am not seeing `Andrea Ligios` posted code. Now i am going to try it by myself and i will show you my try code. Promise i am not seeing Andrea Ligios code. Lets see what will happen...

Comment: The best way to learn. But it is even better if you try before asking the question :))

Comment: @AndreaLigios I posted my code above which i tried.  Please check it above. And give me hint from it.     `Error: There is some mismatch of tags and i am not so much familiar with the the ognl tags`

Comment: It is quite a mess :) but it's good you tried... `<s:set` are not needed or erroneous, `#attr` is not defined here and not what you need, that instead is userStatus and its `index` and `count` properties, that give you the 0-based and 1-based automatically increasing counter). Now you can try my code (and possibly vote / accept)

Comment: I tried your code.its working f9 and i started reading a chaptor called  ''struts2 ognl tags and data binding''.